# Comparable Java Easy method for compare

Tags: java

I'm trying to code a programe for comparing numbers. Here is a method for interface and I don't know what's the problem this method.

```
public class Int implements Comparable {
        private int x;
        public Int(int x){
            this.x=x;
        }
              public int compareTo(Int other){
                  return x - other.x;
              }
```

Comment: You are supposed to tell us what the problem is and what you have tried to do to solve it. Then, we can try to help you.

Comment: Why do you think there's a problem? What isn't working as expected for you?

Comment: Comparable is a generic interface. Your implementation of compareTo does not the override the raw one. Use the @Override annotation and see.

Comment: Inequality operators (<=, >=, <, >) should be used for comparing integers rather then error-prone subtraction. Consider `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1` vs. `0 - 1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `implements Comparable` to `implements Comparable<Int>`.

Another problem is that subtraction based `compareTo` methods don't work as the subtraction can overflow.

Instead use `return x == other.x ? 0 : (x > other.x ? 1 : -1);`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a parameterized type :

```
public class Int implements Comparable<Int>
```

When you use a raw type `Comparable`, your `public int compareTo(Int other)` method doesn't implement the interface's method.